# How to find the maximum value of a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary whose values are the maximums between its first element of the lists that are and its second element of the lists that are, I have created this code but it returns the largest between the first list and the second list, and I don't want that.

```
import numpy as np

dict_pm = {1: [[7560.0, 3346.667], [58440.0, 14653.333]], 
           2: [[460.0, 7500.0], [33460.0, 7500.0]], 
           3: [[3980.0, 1153.333], [12980.0, 10153.333]]}

dict_pm = {key:[np.max(valor[0]),np.max(valor[1]) ] for key, valor in dict_pm.items()}
```

There can be n lists, in short I want my dictionary to look like this:

```
Input: dict_pm = {1: [[7560.0, 3346.667], [58440.0, 14653.333]], 2: [[460.0, 7500.0], [33460.0, 7500.0]], 3: [[3980.0, 1153.333], [12980.0, 10153.333]]}

Output: dict_pm = {1: [58440.0, 14653.333], 2: [33460.0, 7500.0], 3: [12980.0, 10153.333]}
```

My largest list can accommodate more than 2 small lists, in any case the small ones will always have 2 elements but in, the logic would be the same:

```
Input:
dict_pm = {1: [[7560.0, 3346.667], [58440.0, 14653.333], [40.0, 14.33]], 2: [[460.0, 7500.0], [33460.0, 7500.0], [60.0, 7.0]], 3: [[3980.0, 1153.333], [12980.0, 10153.333], [80.0, 1.33]]}

Output:
dict_pm = {1: [58440.0, 14653.333], 2: [33460.0, 7500.0], 3: [12980.0, 10153.333]}
```

Comment: Could not understand what you want to do.
You have a dict composed of numerical keys and each numerical key correspond to a list of lists.
Im troubled with the first phrase "

I'm trying to create a dictionary whose values are the maximums between its first element of the lists that are and its second element of the lists that are,"
Could you explain it better?
If possible give a shorter example with small numbers.

Comment: It's really unclear what your expected output here is. Could you please clarify which of these two are the result you want: 1. `[[10, 20], [1, 40]]` -> `[10,20]` 2. `[[10, 20], [1, 40]]` -> `[10, 40]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `zip` the sub-lists of each `valor` and `map` them to the `max` function instead:

```
{key: list(map(max, zip(*valor))) for key, valor in dict_pm.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sorted` in combination with `dict comprehension`

```
In [8]: {k : sorted(v, key=lambda x : (x[0], x[1]))[-1] for k, v in dict_pm.items()}

Out[8]: {1: [58440.0, 14653.333], 2: [33460.0, 7500.0], 3: [12980.0, 10153.333]}
```